# Mend steel door after break-in attempt

Tags: doors, steel, damage

We had a failed break in attempt into a storage room with a quite thick steel door. See images. The lock itself if not damaged and mechanically sound, so even though it looks pretty bad, it's still just a cosmetic damage.

What would be a viable way to make it look less bad at the very least?

[image: door1]
[image: door2]

Comment: Amateur metalmongering is only likely to make it look ... well not as bad, but clearly worked over good-and-plenty.  You might try to bondo it up, but it's never going to look unmussed, and that will make it attractive for the next thief.  That's the trouble with that kind of door with a lip, it practically invites crowbar use.  I would be talking to a door guy about a new steel door and frame.  You got your moneys worth out of this one.

Comment: Presumably the SAME thief will be back with "better tools" unless they were caught in the act. If this is something like condo/apt storage, it's possibly a co-resident. Agitate for video surveillance of the area pronto.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably bang and trim things back into position and then install a [latch wrap](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-9-in-Stainless-Steel-Door-Guard-U-9586/100285175) (link for reference only) with some stainless sheet metal screws. This will reinforce it and conceal the damaged area.

Comment: @ericurban, please feel free to post your own answer. Your proposed edit was longer than mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a heat gun to heat up the steel and then a heavy hammer to manipulate the steel back to near as flat as you can get it. Use a grinder to take down any high spots that you can not manipulate enough with a hammer. I would then get a piece of 1/8"  steel strap and attach it over the damaged area with security bolts to attach it to the door.

It appears that the door sits flush to the trim so i would have the steel be wide enough to extend over the gap between the door and jamb so that no pry bar can be inserted.

Make sure you prime and paint the damaged area on the door to prevent it rusting in the future.

Comment: A heat gun? Approximately no different than banging on it cold, which will work, to an extent. A torch would make a difference. The correct torch in the correct hands would allow not only banging it flat more easily, but welding on some reinforcement. A good sized adjustable wrench will also be helpful in bending it back. On the third hand, if there's something more worth stealing than the folding chairs in there, replacement/upgrade ASAP might be a good idea....